# Type of member pointer not recognised as <value type>

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, typeid, member-pointers

The following code example tries to extract the value types of member pointer of a struct `foo` previously fed into a function `serialize()`.

This maybe needs further explanation: I want to eventually iterate through each member of the struct `foo` and apply certain operations based on the value types of each member pointer. Have a look:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADsAMykAA6oCoRODB7evv6p6ZkCIWGRLDFxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn4BdpgOWQ1NBCUR0bEJyQqNza15HeP9oYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7BzmiaHI3lgA1CaJbshj%2BKgn2CYaAII7eweYx6dejrSEAJ7Xtw9muwY%2By8RxObgIXhS9F%2B90eQOer3BXxSmFC/BhD3uAHoAFSHBrELwOQ4Ad0ICEOBBJqEOoQIhzYC2ICkOOKxfz%2BY0JxP4V1h8Ss90OwtpgkOTAA%2BidBXcRaL6VEpYkZSZ4gARaUc7F4oRMABumBZjIqhzSdNiLLZWruBEwLChTFtYKY7xpygIxAxXKJ9JSxFQqh%2B/Jlcqw%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%2BCbAoSzwcewoQCYACsVhLWqECzWZQpyieZ7WVxhESsRdkVixGledp3FgmGtDrhAaUPpC9ASjUdqMAQR1gu5UmRjRNmbuOk7Tnubh0dg97rtc96MomyazTBEORrOO0iuZKOAXSVCLWYZjmEtCjLW4DDmAENl4OgEAHdlkZLDlNEbfD807XgJb1WMmCqH6hz3Z1IB4AofUiZxYJ0h1d4gMQdq%2BRuyB6pLVBglTR1I/RMFxkeaPoyKfqY9jZjuSydJgGAhPEzjjOa1rhxYlihxjZbcrOYcNRKMcW2ylbwo64IWMkwbhwMKg9J0oclCmyTFvbZ7Nt2/lDuo2mUdu%2BtKyxzlkcPIncUUUupxJbRP3CT27lhXg01Xje4ssEwADWG7dRzfWYINjCbGCD2Ps9mUbnqVG/TJ64A9uwNgmDiMotBsFKXcxU0kok4VVlEC9i1KmzcGlvz%2BVnxVTVUIQCwrWMQQAEl1Nhoa%2BqGfOdaIfV6EG1zZbvKHFQGjIyKW%2BL1Gb/X%2BqHArFoJwJavA/AcC0KQCCHA3DWGsPWNYGxbIAh4KQAgmgAErBriASQAAOHKOCNCSHiEteI8RPwaESPELgiRJBLX0JwSQoD0GQM4LwIyGhUHoJWHAWAMBEAoDzCkOgsRyCUEikI%2BgcRgBcBxqQLAeoy6YFkngTAJIADyXZOAoJoLdC0lAojMKiKEJoXwtG8EimwQQaiGC0FMeA3gWBq45i2BA/AktugGiMvYwIqgujvBcbwc0QDvGfCiAWYgXwPBYGYR6GqZiVhUAMMABQyjVEaMYGYmQggRBiHYFILJ8glBqGYboLg%2BhDDGFgZYfQeAohGUgCsVASYsheIALQAHUxDllaWolkrTWkXDssABgXgqkWDMBAzo3RnAQFcJMPwZTghzDKBUPQaQMh1GyJ4NoazCibIGCs4YZSpmbN6BMbZeRjmvWmQwM5sxShDDiMcmY8y9BjD6Acx5EgVgKAQZsb59COAgNIGAiBUDDiqBwZ%2BVpn5JCHGAMgZAhwZE5TMNzXAhASDHGQUsXgaD7FLBWAgAKWA4gbUBYw0gLBsFcByokT8pDqEaEIbgyQyRQW8CgWwkAHD8VaG4XwiASA1gEBSO8URdVBHCOIOEESnBIXQthfCxFyKzCot4JgfAu5yZ6H4Nk0Q4h8l6sKSodQ3jSmkBJAWFI8TAXAo5Swjgaj3hivpLWBVMK4UIqRSitFEAPD2mldixIXBcWcIJZgkAS0OHBMpdSpaeDPyJBxlCgAnKmpaS0uAkI0J%2BEFzCuW2B5eG/lkas05S4BmswkgcaJFTZ%2BMwUK83BMSEw7xha%2BUYMBWYNtYLWElq7X5DIzhJBAA%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

/* Struct with two int members */

struct foo
{
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

/* Saves member pointers */

template<auto Ptr>
struct proxy
{
    decltype(Ptr) mem_ptr_;
};

/* Conglomerate of all member ptrs of a struct */

template <typename T>
struct type_descriptor;

template <>
struct type_descriptor<foo>
{
    using type = std::tuple<proxy<&foo::a_>, proxy<&foo::b_>>;
};

/* Extract member ptr value type */

template<typename T>
struct member_pointer_value;

template<typename Class, typename Value>
struct member_pointer_value<Value Class::*>
{
    using type = Value;
};

/* Iterate over each member ptr and compare */

template<typename T, std::size_t... I>
auto serialize_impl(const T& mystruct , std::index_sequence<I...> indices)
{
    ([](){
        using value_type = member_pointer_value<decltype(std::tuple_element_t<I, typename type_descriptor<T>::type>::mem_ptr_)>::type;
        
        printf("%s\n", typeid(value_type).name());
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, std::remove_cvref<value_type>>) {
            printf("Is int!\n");
            // ...
        } else {
            printf("Is not int :(\n");
            // ... 
        }
    }(), ...);
}

template <typename T, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<typename type_descriptor<T>::type>>>
auto serialize(T mystruct)
{
    serialize_impl(mystruct, Indices{});
}

int main()
{
    foo f0;
    serialize(f0);
}
```

**Problem**:

`std::is_same_v` doesn't return true in the constexpr check, so the non-int branch is taken, which is not intended. Interestingly, typeinfo (included for debug purposes only) gives me a type of "i" which I always thought of as "integer"... What is happening?

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing up `std::remove_cvref` and `std::remove_cvref_t`, I believe it's a typo somehow.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7hr6e5n93)